# truffle use without metamask

Tags: truffle, metamask

kindly let me know is that necessary to make use of metamask,my etherwallet or mist with truffle while making coin for ICO launching

Thanks
waiting for your valuable reply

Answer (score 1):

You are not required any other software beyond truffle to deploy and interact with a contract.

But certainly be able to test from a couple of wallets, like Mist or MyEtherWallet can be useful to ensure compatibility with software used by your contributors.